# how to activate a while true statement

Tags: python, function, input, while-loop

so I want to add a while True statement to my code so that way when a variable is false it dosent work but when the variable is changed to true it activates.  in my circumstances I have an open cv camera witch scans QR codes and was wondering how to activate it because it uses a while true statement.  any ideas.  example below

```
hello = false
r = input("hello or hi: ")
if r == 'hi':
hello = True
     while hello = True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
    if bbox is not None:
        for i in range(len(bbox)):
            cv2.line(img, tuple(bbox[i][0]), tuple(bbox[(i + 1) % len(bbox)][0]), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above should also work fine, given that you fix the indentation, and use a break statement to stop the loop whenever you want. https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html

```
hello = false
r = input("hello or hi: ")
if r == 'hi':
    hello = True
while hello = True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
    if bbox is not None:
        for i in range(len(bbox)):
            cv2.line(img, tuple(bbox[i][0]), tuple(bbox[(i + 1) % len(bbox)][0]), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
    break
```

Now the break should be implemented as per your needs. Whenever the break is called, your loop will terminate, so you can implement it in an if statement, or like at the end of the loop, depending upon your usage.

Also you can use an if statement to check if a variable is true, and only then run the while loop. It can be useful when you want a different condition in the while statement.

```
hello = false
r = input("hello or hi: ")
if r == 'hi':
    hello = True
if hello:
    j = 1
    while j < 5:
        _, img = cap.read()
        data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
        if bbox is not None:
            for i in range(len(bbox)):
                cv2.line(img, tuple(bbox[i][0]), tuple(bbox[(i + 1) % len(bbox)][0]), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
        j += 1
```

In the above code, the while loop will only execute when the hello variable is True, and then the while loop will keep iterating until the value of j becomes equal to or greater than 5. You should implement these things according to the requirement in your program, these are the two ways you can do so.